# Related posts PHP affecting facebook comment box

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

My related posts keeps changing my facebook comment box. The comment box will change based on the related posts shown. It should just be focusing on comments for the current page.

Here's my code below.

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

$args=array(
'category__in' => $category_ids,
'post__not_in' => $showed_posts,
'showposts'=>3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts' => 1,
'exclude'          => '$postID',
'orderby' => 'rand'

);
 $my_query = new wp_query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    ?>

<div class="relatedpost">  
<a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(175,98)); ?>
<br />  
<center><h6><?php the_title(); ?></h6></center> 
</a>  
</div>  


<?php
}
    echo '</ul>';
}
}
?>

<center>
<div id="fb-root"></div>  
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>  
<fb:comments href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" width="640"></fb:comments>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the_permalink function to call the comments box, but your related post query affected it, so you need to use `wp_reset_query()`.
I've also add `<li>` in the list and remove the php shortcode `<?` instead `<?php` (For many servers, this not working).

You should try this :

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

    $args=array(
    'category__in' => $category_ids,
    'post__not_in' => $showed_posts,
    'showposts'=>3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'exclude'          => '$postID',
    'orderby' => 'rand'

    );

    $my_query = new wp_query($args);

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            $my_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <li>
            <div class="relatedpost">  
                <a rel="external" href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(175,98)); ?></a>
                <br />  
                <a rel="external" href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><center><h6><?php the_title(); ?></h6></center></a>  
            </div>  
        </li>

    <?php
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }   
}
?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 

<center>
<div id="fb-root"></div>  
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>  
<fb:comments href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" width="640"></fb:comments>
</center>
```